# How to generically populate an object if the field names are provided?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I need to create and populate an object inside a method. The only information is the member field name (passed as a string) and the relevant value for that field (passed as an Object). What is the most appropriate design pattern taking into account performance? - reflection, if comes with a penalty, would not be a preferred approach.

**Update:**
The value to be set comes from an object that acts as a generator of the values having a set of methods that return the proper value for the specific field. E.g. for member `Double x;` it would be `generator.getX()`

Comment: Do you know the type of object you need to create (class name)?

Comment: Reflection necessarily comes with penalty as you have to inspect or search for methods, etc. But that is certainly not noticeable for most usage.

Comment: @someone_somewhere:Yes. It is a specific class

Comment: @Jim look at my answer I think it is what you need.

Comment: So you have a generator or builder with getters and you want to call the setter on the instance of another class with those values?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, call the set passing the value of the proper method of the generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple function to copy all the getters to all the available setters is as follows.  With some more work you can cache this information and speed it up but it is likely to be fast enough as it is.

```
public static <T> T copyTo(Object from, T to) {
    for(Method m : to.getClass().getMethods()) {
        if (!m.getName().startsWith("set") || m.getParameterCount() != 1)
            continue;
        try {
            Method getter = from.getClass().getMethod("g" + m.getName().substring(1));
            m.invoke(to, getter.invoke(from));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
            // ignored
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
    return to;
}
```

Note: Only the fields where there is a matching getter and setter will attempt to copy from one to the other.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    One orig = new One(1, "hi", 3);
    One to = new One();
    One copy = copyTo(orig, to);
    System.out.println(to);
}

static class One {
    int x;
    String y;
    double z;

    public One() {
    }

    public One(int x, String y, double z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    public void setZ(double z) {
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "One{" +
                "x=" + x +
                ", y='" + y + '\'' +
                ", z=" + z +
                '}';
    }
}
```

prints

```
One{x=1, y='hi', z=3.0}
```

---

If you want to create an object generically you need to use reflection.

The only alternative is byte code generation which will be much more complex to implement and only save you a fraction of a micro-second.

How many days is it worth sending to implement this to save a micro-second?

Comment: I don't want to have a generic code for X number of objects. What I want is that if I have specifically a class X and I need to create an array list of instances of that class having only the name of the member fields and the value to set how would I do it in the best structured design. Does this make a difference?

Comment: By the way, is reflection so cheap?

Comment: @Jim Reflection is far more expensive than an assignment. It takes around 100 clocks cycles which is about 35 nano-seconds. An assignment to be less than a nano-second.  The question is, how much effort are you willing to go to to save 35 nano-seconds?

Comment: I see your point. I wanted to avoid unneeded penalties. But how would I use reflection (if I need to) to design what I need? Please check my updated OP

Comment: @Jim I have updated my answer with a simple copier using reflection. The `from` would be your builder/generator with the getters which match those available in the object you are setting.  You can create the object just before calling this if it is a new object.

Comment: For the code to work, wont I need to pass a second parameter to `getMethod`? I.e. the argument's class type?

Comment: I made this to work but it seems I need to pass the parameter type. E.g. `String.class`, `ArrayList.class` etc. I am using a hashmap to map the method names with the expected argument type. Is there a way to do it better? E.g. the generator I use returns an `Object`. So I don't think I can use the return type of that

Comment: @Jim `getMethod` needs a minimum of 1 argument. You don't need to pass parameter type anywhere I can see.

Comment: But I am getting an exception if I don’t pass the argument type. E.g. if the method is `setName(String name)` if I don’t pass as the second argument `String.class` I get an exception of no such method.

Comment: @Jim I have added an example program which runs without error. Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: If I do:  `from.getClass.getMethod(“setName”)` I get:  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setName []`. There is only 1 method defined `setName(String name)` in my class and if I do: `from.getClass.getMethod(“setName”, String.class)` it works. I am on Java 7

Comment: Is it because of Java 7? Is there a clean way to work around this. The extra mapping to contain the types works but seems too hacky

Comment: @Jim it should be calling a getter here not a setter. The first letter should be a "g" not an "s"

Comment: I can’t do it exactly like you mention because the value does not come from the generator. It comes from a stream and the generator knows how to produce the value from that stream. So basically I know the setter name in the target object and I don’t do the loop you mention. So the difference with your example is that I try to get the setter method instead of going over all the method names. So I use your code with the difference that I try to get a specific setter from the target object and I need to glue somehow this

Comment: @Jim If you need to lookup a setter, you need to either know the type, or you need to look for one which matches by name.

Comment: For my other issue if you have time, I have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886382/figure-the-parameter-to-pass-of-the-invocation-of-a-method-via-reflection Might be easier than comments as a separate post

Answer (score 1):

If you know the class name of the object then what you can do is:

```
    public Object populate(String className,String fieldName,Object value) throws Exception{
        Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
        Object o = null;
        for(Field f: clazz.getFields()){
            if(f.getName().equals(fieldName)){
                o =  clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();//default constructor if it exists
                f.set(o, value);
                break;
            }
        }
        return o;
    }
```

EDIT:
Since you know the class(comment under question) then you can use is the function I wrote just with this change and not className parameter:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(YourClass.class.getName());
```

EDIT2:
If I understand the update you are asking about how to know which method to invoke to get the value.
On your generator class you can get the list of methods it has. Then if your method are named getFieldName() you can once you have the field name find the method with the name getFiledName. 
Example:

```
    for(Method m:GeneratorClass.class.getMethods()){
        System.out.println(m.getName());
        //analyze method name and field name to determine which method to call
        //..
        boolean callThis = true;//result of analysis
        if(callThis){
            //Object value = m.invoke(obj);
            //obj==generator
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please see my updated OP. Your answer is very useful +1

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understood the point of the update but see edit2.

Comment: You usually need to execute `f.setAccessible(true)` before setting the field, in case the field is not `public` (which is the usual case).

Comment: The generator object is also of a specific class. It does not have a specific convention to match the field names of the other object thought. I know that for e.g. `Double x` I need to call `generator.getSomeX()` which returns a `Double` or for `ArrayList<Custom> customs` I need to call `generator.getSomeCustoms` that returns an arraylist of such objects

Comment: If it is for x getSomeX and for customs getSomeCustoms then there is some logic what needs to be called.
But otherwise you can hadcode a map that maches field to method and just look that up.

Comment: But what is the idea of the `if(callThis)`?I didn't understand that

Comment: It was if the current method is for the current field then call this method.
So it would be the result of your analysis is the current method the one you need to call to get the value for the current field.