# Figure the parameter to pass of the invocation of a method via reflection

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, reflection, parameters

I have a set of classes that implement generic interface such as:

```
public inteface CustomGenerator {  
   Object generate(Reader r);  
}
```

These classes can process the parameter accordingly and generate the response in the expected type.
I have a base class that I need to populate. To populate class I use these custome generator classes and reflection.

```
public static void copy(CustomClass target, String tag, Reader reader) {  
   Object input = CustomGenerators.get(tag).generate(reader); 
   String setter = setterNames.get(tag);   
   Method m = target.getClass().getMethod(setter, input.getClass());  
   m.invoke(target, input);   
}
```

}

Exception handling omitted for clarity.
This works but I want the address the following:
**Problem:**
Some of the `type`s passed in don't have a custom generator to parse them because they are essentially primitives and 1) I didn't want to create many small classes just to do something trivial like `Integer.valueOf(reader.nextString());`
On the other side, when I call the `target.getClass().getMethod` I need the parameter type and I need to handle the cases of primitive values.
So I would need somehow to figure out here:
`target.getClass().getMethod(setter, input.getClass());` what is the second parameter I need to pass.

How can I cleanly fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason, why you're using `String type` and not `Class<?> clazz` ? Primitive do have corresponding class objects. You can get them as usual: `int.class`, just like you would do `String.class`

Comment: @DzmitryPaulenka: The `type` is not a class. It is a "tag" string that I can understand how to process

Comment: What's "tag" in case of int, for example?

Comment: It is just a stream from a file that has tags and values. It is all predefined and I know that tag e.g. "profit" is something to be parsed as an integer (I mean the associated value; the reader takes care of that)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    static final Map<String, CustomGenerator> generators = new HashMap<String, CustomGenerator>();
    static final Map<String, String> setterNames = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static final Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> wrappers = new HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        wrappers.put(int.class, Integer.class);
        wrappers.put(double.class, Double.class);
        wrappers.put(boolean.class, Boolean.class);
        //...

        generators.put("int", new PrimitiveCustomGenerator(int.class));
        generators.put("double", new PrimitiveCustomGenerator(double.class));
        generators.put("boolean", new PrimitiveCustomGenerator(boolean.class));
        //...

        setterNames.put("int", "setInt");
        //...

        CustomClass holder = new CustomClass();
        System.out.println(holder.intValue);

        copy(holder, "int", new Reader());
        System.out.println(holder.intValue);
    }

    static void assertThat(boolean condition) {
        if (!condition) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    public static class CustomClass {
        private int intValue;

        public void setInt(int intValue) {
            this.intValue = intValue;
        }
    }

    public static void copy(CustomClass target, String tag, Reader reader) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {
        CustomGenerator generator = generators.get(tag);
        Object input = generator.generate(reader);

        String setter = setterNames.get(tag);
        Method m = target.getClass().getMethod(setter, generator.getTargetClass());
        m.invoke(target, input);
    }

    public static class Reader {
        public String nextString() {
            return "22";
        }
    }

    public interface CustomGenerator {
        Class getTargetClass();
        Object generate(Reader r) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException;
    }

    public abstract static class AbstractCustomGenerator implements CustomGenerator {
        protected Class<?> targetClass;

        AbstractCustomGenerator(Class<?> targetClass) {
            this.targetClass = targetClass;
        }

        public Class<?> getTargetClass() {
            return targetClass;
        }
    }

    public static class PrimitiveCustomGenerator extends AbstractCustomGenerator {

        private final Method valueOfMethod;
        private final Class<?> wrapperClass;

        PrimitiveCustomGenerator(Class<?> targetClass) throws NoSuchMethodException {
            super(targetClass);
            assertThat(targetClass.isPrimitive());

            // use google-guava lib
            // Class wrapperClass = com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.wrap(targetClass);
            wrapperClass = wrappers.get(targetClass);

            valueOfMethod = wrapperClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
            assertThat(Modifier.isStatic(valueOfMethod.getModifiers()));
        }

        public Object generate(Reader r) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
            return valueOfMethod.invoke(wrapperClass, r.nextString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting aside the fact that you pass "int" etc while in my case the tag is not the actual type but some descriptive string that the reader can parse the value, your code is similar to what I have more or less. A hashmap for setters and another hashmap to map for the setter names the argument types. I was interested if there was another way/approach to avoid the mapping to argument types if possible

Comment: Ok, I think I understood now :) Well, you can't determine a primitive type from Object, because on that point it's already boxed. So `obj.getClass()` will return `java.lang.Integer`, etc.

Comment: One other way is to use maps of `Method` instances instead of just `setterNames`

Comment: Is there a design pattern that the code structure you posted adheres to?

Comment: I don't know... strategy maybe? why?